# Norm of an operator $T:l^{\infty}\to L^2[0,1]$

Tags: functional-analysis

We have the following operator $T:l^{\infty}\to L^2[0,1]$ with

$T(x=(x_n))=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty x_n \chi_{\left(\frac1{2^n},\frac1{2^{n-1}}\right]}$

I have to prove that $\exists\ y\in l^{\infty}$ with $||y||\leq1$ so that $||T||=||T(y)||$.

Firstly, I proved that $||T||=1$ (Is this correct?). So if I take $y=(1,1,1,...)\in l^{\infty}$ I have solved the problem. Is it something wrong in my argument?

Moreover, I want to decide if $T$ is bounded below ($\exists\ C>0$ so that $||T(x)||\geq C||x||, \forall x\in l^\infty$). I know that the operator is not surjective, but I don't know how to continue. Can somebody help me? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your work is correct, $\|T\|=1$ and the constant sequence gives this upper bound.

However, $T$ is not bounded below.  Consider what it does to the sequence $\{y_n\}$ in $\ell^\infty$ with $y_n(k)=\delta_{n,k}$.